# Al imprimir un carácter UTF-8 por pantalla no se obtiene lo esperado en C++

Tags: c++, utf-8

Estoy manejando el `std::u8string` del módulo `string` de la librería standard, y al querer imprimir por consola algunos caracteres, algunos van bien otros no. Yo comprendo que el emoticono pueda fallar en consola, pero los demás caracteres me resulta extraño que no los imprima, sólo los admitidos por un `char`.
Debo estar haciendo algo mal.

Os muestro el código y os explico lo que hago:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const std::u8string& utf8)
{
    for (wchar_t out : utf8) {
        std::wcout << out;
    }
    return o;
}


int main() {
    std::u8string s { u8"çñü  hasta luego Lucas!!" };
    std::cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Simplemente declaro un std::u8string como s y le asigno una cadena de caracteres.
Después lo quiero imprimir por consola, para lo cual tengo que sobrescrisbir el operador<<.

Comment: En Windows y con el compilador de Microsoft? Funciona terriblemente mal. Necesitas cambiar la codificación de la consola, asegurarte de que el código fuente está en la misma codificación y también cambiar la codificación del compilador.

Comment: ¡OK, le doy una vuelta! Después comento.

Comment: @Mateo, creo que he configurado todo correctamente. Sigue sin funcionar. Sin embargo, si declaras `s2` como `std::string` y tomas los caracteres con un `std::getline(std::cin,s2)` al hacer realizar el `std::cout<<s2` sí que ha tomado los caracteres especiales y los escribe. Eso sí, el cmd, con los emoticonos no puede.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La manera que encontré de imprimir caracteres Unicode en el código fuente con `cout` es la siguiente:

- **Cambiar la codificación de la consola:**

  ```
  SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
  ```

  Para más información consulta la [lista de codificaciones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers).
- **Cambiar la codificación del compilador:**

  Para esto debes abrir la configuración del proyecto, dirigirte a la sección **C/C++**, **Command Line** y en opciones adicionales agregas [**`/utf-8`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8). Recuerda aplicar el ajuste a todas las configuraciones y plataformas.

  [image: Captura de la configuración del proyecto]
- **Cambiar la codificación del código fuente.**

  Si hiciste todos los pasos anteriores, se verá el caracter esperado al imprimir sus bytes. Por ejemplo los de la [ñ](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00F1):

  ```
  const char* ñ = "\xC3\xB1";
  std::cout << ñ;
  ```

  Pero no necesariamente tendrás la suerte de que un literal con la ñ se vea bien:

  ```
  const char* ñ = "ñ";
  std::cout << ñ;
  ```

  Para asegurarte de que se vea bien, la codificación del código fuente también debe ser Unicode. Puedes modificarla desde tu editor de texto favorito, como Visual Studio Code.

  Algunos links útiles:

  - [How to set standard encoding in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1875622/13419694)
  - [How to: Save and open files with encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-save-and-open-files-with-encoding#to-save-a-file-with-encoding)

---

En cuanto a la lectura, no encontré cómo hacerlo con `cin` pero sí con [`ReadConsole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsole) y [`MultiByteToWideChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte):

- Cambiar la codificación de entrada de la consola:

  ```
  SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8);
  ```
- Obtener la entrada y convertirla.

  ```
  const int maximo = 20;
  WCHAR buffer[maximo] = L"";
  DWORD caracteresLeidos = 0;
  ReadConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), buffer, maximo, &caracteresLeidos, nullptr);

  // Para poder imprimir la entrada con cout es necesario convertirla
  char bufferUTF8[maximo] = "";
  WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, buffer, caracteresLeidos, bufferUTF8, sizeof(bufferUTF8), nullptr, nullptr);
  std::cout << bufferUTF8;
  ```

  Si prefieres usar [`WriteConsole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole) puedes imprimir directamente la variable `buffer`, es decir, lo que leyó `ReadConsole`.

  ```
  WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), buffer, caracteresLeidos, nullptr, nullptr);
  ```

  Si intentas imprimir el contenido de `bufferUTF8` con esta función obtendrás caracteres extraños. Por lo que necesitarás hacer la conversión inversa.

  ```
  MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, bufferUTF8, caracteresLeidos, buffer, maximo);
  ```

Comment: solucionas el problema. Lo que echo en falta es que con la propia biblioteca estándar no se solucione, por lo menos, con VS 2022 y el compilador propio a éste

Comment: @Caba no entiendo. Te funcionó mí respuesta?

Comment: completamente. Lo que me indicas funciona a la perfección.