# Mostrar texto unicode en SFML (C++)

Tags: c++, unicode, sfml

Estoy tratando de mostrar texto en una ventana usando la biblioteca SFML de C++. Sin embargo, los carácteres como vocales con acentos, eñe, etc, no se imprimen correctamente en pantalla. En cambio si los envío a la consola usando `cout` no hay problema, se imprimen correctamente.

Este es un ejemplo mínimo:

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#define FONT_PATH "C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial.ttf"

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML window");

    sf::Font font;

    if (!font.loadFromFile(FONT_PATH)) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    sf::Text text;
    text.setFont(font);
    text.setColor(sf::Color::White);
    text.setString(L"Algunos carácteres: ¡ñáéíóú");
    text.setCharacterSize(24);

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(text);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Y se renderiza de esta manera:
[image: Renderización incorrecta de texto]

Aunque no sé si es relevante, este es el contenido de CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(prueba LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(SFML
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/SFML/SFML.git
    GIT_TAG 2.6.x)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(SFML)

add_executable(prueba src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(prueba PRIVATE sfml-graphics)
target_compile_features(prueba PRIVATE cxx_std_17)

if(WIN32)
    add_custom_command(
        TARGET prueba
        COMMENT "Copy OpenAL DLL"
        PRE_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${SFML_SOURCE_DIR}/extlibs/bin/$<IF:$<BOOL:${ARCH_64BITS}>,x64,x86>/openal32.dll $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:prueba>
        VERBATIM)
endif()

install(TARGETS prueba)
```

He probado usando `std::wstring`, `sf::String`, añadiendo o eliminando prefijos como `u8`, `U`, `L` a la cadena, y ninguna de estas formas funciona. Algunas no compilan y otras muestran carácteres incorrectos diferentes.

Comment: Probablemente los caracteres especiales no se estén guardando bien en el código fuente. Intenta hacer lo segundo y tercero que menciono en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/599328/169744)

Comment: intenta usarlo de esta manera, podría ser por `encoding utf-8` ...  `window.setUnicodeEncoding(true);`  ...  `text.setString(L"Algunos carácteres: ¡ñáéíóú");`

Comment: @cardosource No entiendo dónde pondrías `encoding utf-8`. En todo caso, me aparece este error: `"setUnicodeEncoding": no es un miembro de "sf::RenderWindow"`.