# Problema al mostrar caracteres con ncurses en windows

Tags: c++, ascii, mingw

Tengo el siguiente código que esperaría que imprima una "á" en la consola:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
  initscr();                      /* Inicia el modo curses          */
  printw("á");      
  refresh();                      /* Imprimirlo en la pantalla real */
  getch();                        /* Esperar entrada de usuario     */
  endwin();                       /* Terminar el modo curses        */

  return 0;
}
```

En Ubuntu mate 22.04 funciona tal cuál lo esperaría, imprime correctamente "á".

Sin embargo no estoy logrando hacerlo funcionar correctamente en Windows.

Lo compilo usando el siguiente comando:

`C:\msys64\mingw64.exe g++ -o hello hello.cpp -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/ncursesw -lncursesw`

Pero cuando lo voy a ejecutar me muestra: `Ã¡`. En vez de `á`.

Lo que pensé que podía llegar a ser el problema es que ncurses estuviera mandando los caracteres en UTF-8 y cmd los estuviera intentando interpretar como si fuera un ascii extendido con la página de códigos 850 (que es la que uso en CMD).

Lo que me lleva a pensar eso es justo los caracteres que aparecen.

á en UTF-8 es: 0xC3 0xA1
y justo se da que en cp850: 0xC3 = Ã y 0xA1 = ¡.

Entonces teniendo eso en cuenta supuse que si podía configurar CMD para usar UTF-8 se iba a solucionar mi problema, para ello modifique un poco el código:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
  SetConsoleCP(65001);
  SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
  initscr();                      /* Inicia el modo curses          */
  printw("á");      
  refresh();                      /* Imprimirlo en la pantalla real */
  getch();                        /* Esperar entrada de usuario     */
  endwin();                       /* Terminar el modo curses        */

  return 0;
}
```

Pero da la misma salida indeseada.

Otra cosa que podría intentar es configurar msys64, mingw, gcc, ncurses (? (sinceramente no sé de quien depende) para que ncurses saque los caracteres usando el ascii extendido con cp850. Pero no sé como hacerlo.

¿Alguien sabe que puede estar pasando?

Los únicos caracteres que quiero mostrar que son "raros" (no parte de us-ascii) son los usados en el español: "ñáéíóú", que están presentes en el ascii extendido con cp850. Así que estimo que con ascii extendido con cp850 me es suficiente (no requiero realmente unicode).

Comment: Probaste con `printf`? Te dejo un par de respuestas que di por si te sirven https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/604476/169744 https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/599328/169744

Comment: Con printf se muestra bien la "á" pero cuando ya salió del modo ncurses. Puedo intentar con WriteConsoleW pero me parece que va a tener el mismo problema que menciono con printf.

Lo de cambiar la codificación de la consola que mencionan en el segundo link ya lo intenté. Francamente no sé como cambiar la codificación del compilador. 

Aclaro que las cosas que imprimo con std::cout se muestran genial (sin tener que usar SetConsoleCP(65001) ni na') .

Comment: No, no va a tener ningún problema si utilizas las funciones con la W ni necesitas cambiar la página de códigos con `SetConsoleCP` ni `SetConsoleOutputCP`. Estas funciones utilizan UTF-16 en lugar de UTF-8. Por ejemplo: `WriteConsoleW(GetConsoleHandle(), L"áéíóú", 5, nullptr, nullptr)`

Comment: me sale "error: 'GetConsoleHandle' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'GetConsoleWindow'?"

Comment: Me confundí. Era `GetStdHandle(STDOUT)`, no `GetConsoleHandle`.

Comment: Me da " error: 'STDOUT' was not declared in this scope". Pensé en cambiarlo a minúscula a ver si agarraba pero ahí me da: " error: invalid conversion from 'FILE*' {aka '_iobuf*'} to 'DWORD' {aka 'long unsigned int'} [-fpermissive]" en la línea donde tengo el WriteConsoleW

Comment: Disculpa nuevamente me equivoqué porque [aquí](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-handles) dice STDOUT. Es [STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle).  Así debería funcionar `WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), L"áéíóú", 5, nullptr, nullptr)`.

Comment: Ahora pasó lo mismo que con printf. Sí, con esa línea se muestra bien el "áéíóú" pero recién se muestra una vez terminado el modo ncurses. Aclaro que puse el ```WriteConsoleW``` arriba del refresh y abajo del initscr