# ¿Por qué no funciona la librería <locale.h> en mi compilador de C++?

Tags: c++, dev-c++, compilar, caracteres, acentos

Quiero usar la librería #include<locale.h> en mis códigos de C++ para imprimir acentos con la función cout, pero no funciona. He probado con algunas variantes que encontré en internet y nada.

Actualmente estoy simplemente probando con este código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Spanish");
        
    cout<<"á é í ó ú ñ";

    return 0;
}
```

Al compilar se imprime: Ã¡ Ã© Ã­ Ã³ Ãº Ã±

Uso la versión 6.3 de C++

Comment: Bienvenido. Hay preguntas similares, por favor buscalas. Por cierto, `setlocale` es para localización, y hace cosas como modificar el formato numérico. La solución pasa por cambiar la codificación a Unicode con `SetConsoleOutputCP(65001)`

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Al imprimir un carácter UTF-8 por pantalla no se obtiene lo esperado en C++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/599284/al-imprimir-un-car%c3%a1cter-utf-8-por-pantalla-no-se-obtiene-lo-esperado-en-c)