# Imprimir la letra "ó" arroja "Ã³" en Visual Studio C++ 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio, caracteres, imprimir

Espero que estén bien. Soy nuevo aprendiendo programación en C++, ojalá me puedan ayudar con este problema.

Ahora mismo estoy tratando de seguir un tutorial de introducción. Entendí más o menos como modificarlo, así que quise escribir en español las frases a imprimir del programa:

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Aplicación de Calculadora en Consola" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Por favor inserte la operación a ejecutar. Formato: a+b | a-b | a*n | a/b"
  << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Una vez iniciado el programa, el resultado esperado sería:

> Aplicación de Calculadora en Consola
>
> Por favor inserte la operación a ejecutar. Formato: a+b | a-b | a*n | a/b
>
> C:\Users\LFACC\source\repos\Tutorial de calculadora\x64\Debug\Tutorial de calculadora.exe > (proceso 17056) se cerró con el código 0.
> Presione cualquier tecla para cerrar esta ventana. . .

En su lugar, me arroja lo siguiente:

> AplicaciÃ³n de Calculadora en Consola
>
> Por favor inserte la operaciÃ³n a ejecutar. Formato: a+b | a-b | a*n | a/b
>
> C:\Users\LFACC\source\repos\Tutorial de calculadora\x64\Debug\Tutorial de calculadora.exe (proceso 17056) se cerró con el código 0.
> Presione cualquier tecla para cerrar esta ventana. . .

Al tratar de resolver el problema, busqué alguna solución en internet, modificando el código incluyendo estas bibliotecas y unas instrucciones para ver si se arreglaba, pero no funcionó. dejo aquí una copia.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");
SetConsoleCP(1252);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1252);
cout << "Aplicación de Calculadora en Consola" << endl << endl;
cout << "Por favor inserte la operación a ejecutar. Formato: a+b | a-b | a*n | a/b"
    << endl;
return 0;
}
```

(actualización)
He revisado otras preguntas recomendadas que tratan de responder esta pregunta y me han ayudado para resolver el problema:

- [Al imprimir un carácter UTF-8 por pantalla no se obtiene lo esperado en C++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/599284/al-imprimir-un-car%C3%A1cter-utf-8-por-pantalla-no-se-obtiene-lo-esperado-en-c?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Tabla de caracteres ASCII Windows-1252](https://www.ascii-code.com/)

con esto, simplemente reemplacé la "ó" por su hexadecimal, quedando una versión simplificada del código presentado aquí arriba con esta diferencia:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");
    cout << "Aplicaci\xF3n de Calculadora en Consola" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Por favor inserte la operaci\xF3n a ejecutar. Formato: a+b | a-b | a*n | a/b"
        << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Sólo me queda pendiente saber cómo setear el programa para que todo texto impreso se lea correctamente sin recurrir a reemplazos por hexadecimales.
gracias nuevamente por leer y por la pronta respuesta.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Al imprimir un carácter UTF-8 por pantalla no se obtiene lo esperado en C++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/599284/al-imprimir-un-car%c3%a1cter-utf-8-por-pantalla-no-se-obtiene-lo-esperado-en-c)

Comment: La codificación de la consola como del código fuente deben ser la misma. De lo contrario los literales se mostrarán incorrectamente. Con la [codificación 1252](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), el byte F3 debería imprimirse como **ó**.

Comment: muchas gracias por responder, fueron muy útiles tus comentarios.

Comment: @Mateo por fin pude verificar tu último comentario, mi windows y la consola estaban configuradas en 850 latin por defecto, mientras que mi VS estaba en UTF-8. dejo el artículo que me ayudó a arreglarlo. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131654/using-utf-8-encoding-chcp-65001-in-command-prompt-windows-powershell-window#57134096

Comment: O puedes usar `SetConsoleOutputCP(65001)` para cambiarla a UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

Encontré la solución. tal como comentaban, mi problema era la consola fuente y la consola de salida trabajan en codificaciones distintas. mientras que mi proyecto está seteado en 65001 UTF-8, la consola de windows trabajaba en 850 DOS latin.

esto producía que los caracteres especiales se mostraran incorrectamente. la forma de resolverlo la encontré [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131654/using-utf-8-encoding-chcp-65001-in-command-prompt-windows-powershell-window#57134096), seteando la computadora en UTF-8.
la otra forma más inmediata de resolver esto es incluir el `SetConsoleOutputCP(65001)` en el programa, incluyendo la biblioteca `<stdio.h>`.

al final el código quedó así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
    cout << "Aplicación de Calculadora en Consola" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Por favor inserte la operación a ejecutar. Formato: a+b | a-b | a*n | a/b"
        << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Esto debería funcionar, en mi caso ya no estoy usando el outputCP ya que la consola quedó configurada manualmente.
Muchas gracias a todos por su valioso tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar **secuencias de escape Unicode**, lo cual permite representar cualquier caracter de **16 bits**. El formato  para usar la secuencia de escape es **\uhhhh**, donde **hhhh** es un número hexadecimal de cuatro dígitos. Por tanto para escribir el texto **"Aplicación"** podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
cout << "\u0041\u0070\u006c\u0069\u0063\u0061\u0063\u0069\u00f3\u006e";
```

**Referencia**: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/win32/intl/unicode

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Buscando durante el día encontré un link que me sirvió para setear mi consola y el windows en UTF-8, eso junto a configurar las propiedades del proyecto para que coincida con la misma. eso resolvió el problema. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131654/using-utf-8-encoding-chcp-65001-in-command-prompt-windows-powershell-window#57134096