# ¿Cómo puedo usar UTF-8 en C++?

Tags: c++, utf-8

Quiero usar **caracteres especiales** como ñ o acentos, pero no puedo por el **UTF-8**.
Uso **Windows 11**.
Compilador TDM-GCC: versión 10.3.0.
Utilizó **cout** y **std::string**.

Comment: Por si 2 respuestas fueran poco, hay más preguntas como esta. Por favor busquen un poco antes de preguntar lo mismo. Por ejemplo https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/613405/169744

Comment: Ya las revisé y ya había buscado antes de preguntar, pero ninguna me ha servido.

Comment: Qué extraño. ¿Entonces cómo estás tratando de imprimir los caracteres especiales? ¿Con un literal tal vez (`cout << "lo que sea"`)?

Comment: Exacto, es con un literal cout

Comment: Me descargué el compilador. Sí me funciona usar `SetConsoleOutputCP(65001)` (para cambiar a UTF-8) e imprimir un literal. El único detalle es que por algún motivo no se imprime bien en la consola de mingw pero sí en cmd. El comando que use para compilarlo es `g++ especial.cpp -o especial.exe`

Comment: Gracias, lo voy a probar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para C++ desde el estandar 11 puedes utilizar la notacion `u8` antes de los `std::string` o `std::string_view`

Por ejemplo

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    auto s = std::vector<std::string_view> {
      
        u8"▄▄▄▄▄ ",
        u8"█   █ ",
        u8"█ ▄▀█ ",
        u8"█▀  █ ",
        u8"▀▀▀▀▀ ",
      
    };
    
    for (const auto& line : s) {
        std::cout << line << "\n";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Solo asegurate de que tu consola soporte utf-8 porque la que viene por defecto en windows esta hecha solo para ASCII (excepto por Windows Terminal)

Comment: El detalle es que a partir de C++20 los literales u8 tienen su propio tipo, ya no es `char` y no pueden ser impresos directamente. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Comment: @Mateo por fortuna, actualmente el estandar predefinido en gcc/mingw es el 17 y en msvc es el 14

Comment: Además de que lo puedes cambiar al que te guste. [No sé por qué hicieron eso](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55556200/13419694). Aunque posiblemente con un `reinterpret_cast` a `char*` funcione.

Answer (score -3):

Piensa que los caracteres especiales tienen su valor asociado en carácter ASCII, por lo que puedes identificar el carácter que quieras a dicho valor. Por ejemplo como está en este código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // Imprimir la Ñ utilizando su valor ASCII
    printf("Sacamos la %c por su valor ASCII\n", 209);

    return 0;
}
```

Además, te recomiendo comprobar las siguientes opciones:

1. Asegúrate de que tu archivo fuente esté codificado como UTF-8: Abre tu archivo fuente en un editor de texto como Notepad++ o Visual Studio Code y verifica que esté guardado con la codificación UTF-8. Deberías tener la opción de guardar el archivo con una codificación específica en el menú del editor.
2. Configura la codificación en tu entorno de compilación: Si estás utilizando algún IDE o entorno de desarrollo específico, verifica la configuración para asegurarte de que la codificación del proyecto esté establecida en UTF-8.
3. Asegúrate de que tu terminal o consola de comandos admita UTF-8: Si estás ejecutando tu programa desde la línea de comandos, asegúrate de que la consola esté configurada para admitir UTF-8. Puedes configurar esto cambiando la fuente y la configuración de la consola en la ventana de propiedades de la consola.
4. Compila tu programa utilizando la opción correcta: Asegúrate de que estás compilando tu programa con la opción adecuada para indicarle al compilador que el código fuente está en UTF-8. En GCC, puedes usar la opción -finput-charset=UTF-8 para lograr esto.

Por ejemplo, para compilar un programa llamado mi_programa.c con TDM-GCC en Windows 11, podrías usar el siguiente comando en la línea de comandos:

`gcc -o mi_programa mi_programa.c -finput-charset=UTF-8`

Comment: Esto parece copiado de chatgpt

Comment: El problema es que yo uso cout, no printf.

Comment: @Reymon aún así puedes aplicar la misma solución. Ya sea usando printf en C++, `cout << (char)codigo_ascii` o `cout.put(codigo_ascii)`

Comment: Podrías darme un ejemplo de uso, por favor.

Comment: @Reymon por ejemplo, [GetConsoleOutputCP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsoleoutputcp) en mi PC dice que la codificación activa es la 850. Si quiero imprimir la ñ miro [la tabla](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A1gina_de_c%C3%B3digos_850) y puedo usar `cout.put(164)` (164 es el código de la ñ).

Comment: Gracias, eso me ayudó.

Comment: esto es para lenguaje C